# populating null rows in table column based on matching IDs via join or otherwise

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, vertica

Just to level set: i'm working within a Vertica database using SQL.

Let's say i have two tables: Table A and Table B. Let's also say that Table A is my final/master table used for data vis within Tableau (or something akin), and that Table B feeds certain columns into Table A based on matches within a tertiary table, Table C (which is not relevant to this conversation).

As is, Table A has columns:

```
ProgramName [varchar(50)]
CustomerName [varchar(50)]
Total_Cost [numeric(18,4)]
```

As is, Table B has columns:

```
CustomerCode [varchar(10)]
Total_Cost [numeric(18,4)]
```

What I would like to do is update Table A's CustomerName column to equal CustomerCode in Table B where the columns of total_cost_dollars equal each other across tables.

I've run this left join query to ensure that, when I do update Table A's CustomerName to equal CustomerCode, the total cost columns are exact/true matches for my entire data set.

```
SELECT
    A.ProgramName,
    A.CustomerName,
    A.total_cost_dollars,
    B.CustomerCode,
    B.total_cost_dollars
FROM
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN
    TableB B
ON
    B.total_cost_dollars = A.total_cost_dollars
WHERE
    A.CustomerName IS NULL;
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail

Comment: hey @JimMacaulay - happy to do so. my end goal here is to populate TableA's CustomerName column (as is, the column is entirely null) with what is resident in TableB's CustomerCode column (as  is, the column is entirely populated). I will ensure that what i insert into TA.CustomerName is accurate by matching on a common column between the two tables - total_cost.

Comment: @JimMacaulay is there a specific area of the problem you would like me to provide more detail?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please show what you are able to do. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] [help]

Answer (score 0):

Since Vertica supports merge query, you can use merge statement:

```
merge into TableA A
using TableB B
ON (B.total_cost_dollars = A.total_cost_dollars)
when matched then
update
set
A.CustomerName = B.CustomerCode
where
A.CustomerName IS NULL;
```